# Getting "Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins" error during ripping

Tags: python, music, rhythmbox, ogg-vorbis

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 from a flash drive that you create from the official ubuntu website. I am getting some errors on the system quite frequently. I have tried redoing it but I keep having the same problems. I am using a Dell Latitude E6400.

The biggest error that I keep running into and no one has been able to answer is when I try ripping a cd using Rhythmbox. I have tried other software to rip the CD but keep getting the same error regardless of what software I use. This is the error I get.

> "Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to create media files of the following type: Vorbis encoder"

Now I have installed every Python package I can find. I uninstalled Rhythmbox and reinstalled it. When this message comes up there is a the option to "Install" the missing plugin. I click it and it also informs me of an error about the package not found.

I would appreciate any help I can get from anyone. Ubuntu 12.10 looks like it has some nice features but it so far has been nothing but frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the actual library that the Python module is a wrapper for: libvorbis.  In the terminal, try:

```
sudo apt-get install libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3
```

Comment: May as well run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` so he doesn't see any similar messages about other codecs in the future.